# SQL grouping averages per year

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a SQL query that looks like this

```
SELECT 
    `table`.Property AS 'Property',
    AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price'
FROM
    `table`
WHERE 
    `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
GROUP BY 
    `table`.Property
ORDER BY 
    `table`.Property ASC
```

and this returns a result like:

```
| Property | Average Sold Price |
|    D     | 1890895.381275497  |
|    F     | 528221.9917672797  |
|    S     | 985241.5226100162  |
|    T     | 941906.3221196578  |
```

How would I adapt the query to do an average per year to create an output like this -- there is a column called "Year"

```
| Property | Avg Sold Price 2016 | Avg Sold Price 2015 | Avg Sold Price 2014 |  
|    D     | 1890895.381275497   | 1690895.381275497   | 1490895.381275497   |
|    F     | 528221.9917672797   | 518221.9917672797   | 618221.9917672797   |
|    S     | 985241.5226100162   | 955241.5226100162   | 755241.5226100162   |
|    T     | 941906.3221196578   | 911901.3221196578   | 781901.3221196578   |
```

Comment: Considering handling issues of data display in a presentation layer/application level  code, if that's available. I thought about buying a flat in NW1 in 2104. Glad I didn't!

Comment: @Strawberry :) I think that is fake data -- I just quickly made the coloumn to demonstrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
`table`.Property AS 'Property',
`table`.Year AS 'Year',
AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price'
FROM
`table`
WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
GROUP BY `table`.Property,`table`.Year
ORDER BY `table`.Property ASC
```

Comment: Cheers I will go with this one

Answer (score 1):

Update: I tried it in oracle and it works. So you try something like below.

```
SELECT 
`table`.Property AS 'Property',
AVG(case when Year=2016 then `table`.`Value` end) AS 'Average Sold Price 2016',
AVG(case when Year=2015 then `table`.`Value` end) AS 'Average Sold Price 2015',
AVG(case when Year=2014 then `table`.`Value` end) AS 'Average Sold Price 2014'
FROM
`table`
WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
GROUP BY `table`.Property,`table`.Year
ORDER BY `table`.Property ASC
```

In case it doesn't work, you can use an alternate approach like below.

Then idea is to calculate each `average` for `year` separately and then use this resultset to join based on `property`. `Full outer join` is used to make sure we add entry for isolated combination also. The `coalesce` is just to take care of null and use other `year` if that happens.

```
select coalesce(y2014.'Property',y2015.'Property',y2016.'Property') as Property
,y2014.'Average Sold Price'
,y2015.'Average Sold Price'
,y2016.'Average Sold Price' from
    (
    select `table`.Property AS 'Property',`table`.Year as Year
    AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price'
    FROM
    `table`
    WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
    and `table`.Year=2014
    GROUP BY `table`.Property,`table`.Year
    ) y2014
full outer join
    (
    select `table`.Property AS 'Property',`table`.Year as Year
    AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price'
    FROM
    `table`
    WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
    and `table`.Year=2015
    GROUP BY `table`.Property,`table`.Year
    ) y2015
on y2014.'Property'=y2015.'Property'
    full outer join
    (
    select `table`.Property AS 'Property',`table`.Year as Year
    AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price'
    FROM
    `table`
    WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
    and `table`.Year=2016
    GROUP BY `table`.Property,`table`.Year
    ) y2016
on y2015.'Property'=y2016.'Property'
```

Note: I am assuming `Year` is a string but if it is not, then use the appropriate conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data using sum() function, query will be like this :

```
     SELECT 
`table`.Property AS 'Property',
AVG(`table`.`Value`) AS 'Average Sold Price',
AVG(SUM(IF(table.Year=2016,`table`.`Value`,0))) AS 'Average Sold Price 2016',
AVG(SUM(IF(table.Year=2015,`table`.`Value`,0))) AS 'Average Sold Price 2015',
AVG(SUM(IF(table.Year=2014,`table`.`Value`,0))) AS 'Average Sold Price 2014',
FROM
`table`
WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE '%NW1%'
GROUP BY `table`.Property
ORDER BY `table`.Property ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will enable you to have dynamic column results:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'AVG(IF(Year = ''',Year,
      ''',`Value`,0)) AS AvgSoldPrice', Year)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from `table`;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `table`.Property,', @sql, ' WHERE `table`.`Area` LIKE ''%NW1%''
GROUP BY `table`.Property
ORDER BY `table`.Property ASC');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```